# Chain rule with exponential map

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, lie-groups, chain-rule

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $X,Y \in $ Lie($G$) and $f \in C^{\infty}(G)$. Then, by the chain rule:

$\frac{d}{dt} \Bigr \lvert_{t=0} f(exp(tX)exp(tY)) = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr \lvert_{t=0} f(exp(tX)exp(0 \cdot Y))+ \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr \lvert_{t=0} f(exp(0 \cdot X)exp(tY)) = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr \lvert_{t=0} f(exp(tX)) + \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr \lvert_{t=0} f(exp(tY)) = Xf + Yf$.

I don't get the first equality. Could someone give me a hand with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce the function $F(s,t) = f\big(\exp(sX)\exp(tY)\big)$ and differentiate $F(s,t)$. Then set $\phi(t) = (t,t)$ and apply the chain rule to differentiate $F(\phi(t))$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't get it. For example, I have:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Bigr \lvert_{s=0} F(s,t) =\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Bigr \lvert_{s=0} f(exp(tX)exp(0 \cdot Y)) \cdot Y exp(tX)$. I probably do something wrong with my inner derivative, but I don't understand what and why. Thanks for the help!

Comment: At $(s,t)=(0,0)$, we have $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}(0,0) = \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} F(s,0) = \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} f(\exp(sX)) = df_e(X) = Xf(e)$.

Comment: All clear, thank you!